# Reading from a binary file a structure with dynamically allocated variables

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, binary

I have 2 structures, which have dynamically allocated variables. One structure contains an array made of elements defined in the fisrt structure. The definitions look something like this.

```
typedef struct entry {
    char *key;
    int value;
} entry;

typedef struct map {
    entry **elem;
    int nr_elem;
    int cap;
} map;
```

Basically I have to read my data from a binary format file. However I cannot read at once the whole map block as I cannot specify a certain size. My only information is that each string key, in all of my entries ends with `\0`, however they may have any size, therefore I cannot use `fread` either for my entries. What would be a good workaround for this situation, given that I can only read in binary format?

Comment: How do these two structures appear in the file? Can they be in *any* order? If there is any logic in the file, there should be a `map` first, followed by `n_elem` `entry` types. It makes no sense to store the `map`s property `**elem` in the file - how was that done? Ah - can you post your data file on a public server and add a link to your post?

Comment: You need to know how the data was written if you want to read it back. The write would have had the same issues - the whole `map` could not have been written in one go (if it was then you need to go back and fix the write code as that would be broken). So if it was done properly the data must have been serialised in a particular way. You need to know the exact serialisation before you can read it back.

Comment: I am given the number of entries, followed by each individual possible entry, followed by the map which doesn't necessarily contain all entries.

Comment: That's not good enough as an explanation. Coding needs to be precise and that statement can be interpreted in multiple ways. If you want help please show at least the exact write code. See [How to create a minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The file format must be specified more precisely.

The specification for a binary file format must be very concise:

- How are numbers encoded? How many bytes, little-endian or big-endian?
- How are strings encoded and terminated?
- How are records separated?

Once you know these details, make sure you `fopen` the file in binary mode with `"rb"`, and read the file byte by byte with `fgetc()`. handling the encoding appropriately.

Note that writing the numbers with `fwrite` is not recommended as the endianness of the writer and the reader platforms might differ, as well as the size of `int`.

It is much more flexible to use textual formats.  It makes it **much** easier to debug, interoperate, create by hand...  Only use binary formats if you are required to.